# So.. what exactly is Partition of an Interval

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I have been researching about Partition of an Interval, and I'm quite confused.

Some articles(Peoples) say Partition of $[a,b]$ is a finite sequence of $ a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdot\cdot\cdot < x_n=b$ which is $P={\{x_0, x_1, \cdot\cdot\cdot, x_n}\}$ and $[x_0, x_1], [x_1, x_2], \cdot\cdot\cdot, [x_{n-1}, x_n]$ is the subintervals of Partition P

while others say its a set of subdivided subintervals $P={\{[x_0, x_1], [x_1,x_2]}, \cdot\cdot\cdot, [x_{n-1}, x_n\}$

so as in the title, what exactly is a Partition of $[a,b]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the same term gets used in multiple different ways in mathematics. This can be extremely annoying (cf. the common confusion around the notion of "function," discussed e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777563/codomain-of-a-function)). Technically, this is one such occasion.

However, note that the two definitions cited are equivalent in a precise sense: there is an explicit way to translate between the two notions. Given a "first-type partition" $\langle a=x_0,x_1,...,x_n=b\rangle$, we get a corresponding "second-type partition" $\{[a=x_0, x_1], [x_1, x_2],...,[x_{n-1},x_n=b]\}$ (and we can translate in the other direction too). This means that neither notion has more, or different, information than the other, and the conflation of the two is relatively benign.

Comment: so we can think of ${\{a=x_0, x_1, \cdot\cdot\cdot, x_n=b}\}$ as a partition "acting" an a interval $[a,b]$ and ${\{[x_0, x_1], [x_1, x_2], \cdot\cdot\cdot, [x_{n-1}, x_n]}\}$ as the result of that action, and vice versa?

Comment: @JohnDoe Sounds right, although I'd avoid the term "acting" in this context since [it has an established (and unrelated) meaning in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).

Comment: what representation would you recommend others to use, in studies or in writing an article using partition

Comment: @JohnDoe I don't think there's a particular advantage to either, as long as the author is explicit and consistent in their usage.

Comment: Somehow this nice answer hasn't received any votes so far. +1 there.