# Find a function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ such that $f_n \to f$ on $[0,1]$ where $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$.

Tags: solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions with
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}.$$
Find a function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ such that $f_n \to f$ on $[0,1]$.

I know that this sequence of function is the partial sum of the Maclaurin series of $\cos x$, and so, $f_n \to f$ on $[0,1]$, where $f(x)=\cos x$. But, the codomain of $f$ is not $\Bbb R$, but $[-1,1]$. How to approach this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ means that the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$? I think it only means that the codomain is *contained in* $\mathbb{R}$, so you can just take $f(x) = \cos x$.

Comment: The codomain is not the same as the image. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/777563/473276). So long as for each $x \in X$, we have $f(x) \in Y$, then $f$ is a function $X \to Y$, which is true in this case. I think Seewoo Lee's comment is confusing because $f: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ absolutely *does* mean that the codomain is $\Bbb R$, it just doesn't mean that $\Bbb R$ is the image.